# Get all possible exports from module by TypeScript API or ts-morph

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

```
// sourceFileContent
import path from 'path';
```

```
// Short version of node_modules/@types/node/path.d.ts
declare module 'path' {
    namespace path {
        interface ParsedPath {}
        interface FormatInputPathObject {}
        interface PlatformPath {
            normalize(p: string): string;
            join(...paths: string[]): string;
            // other...
        }
    }
    const path: path.PlatformPath;
    export = path;
}
```

Code below is written using `ts-morph` which is wrapper around typescript

```
const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile('source.ts', sourceFileContent);
const importDeclarations = sourceFile.getImportDeclarations();

// loop for importDeclarations
let symbol = importDeclaration.getImportClause().getSymbol();
symbol = typeChecker.getAliasedSymbol(symbol);
const exportSymbols = typeChecker.getExportsOfModule(symbol);
// {"ParsedPath" => SymbolObject, "FormatInputPathObject" => SymbolObject, "PlatformPath" => SymbolObject}
```

Here I got three export symbols, but we know about `normalize`, `join` and other functions that should exists in `path` module.

```
import { normalize, join } from 'path'; // no errors
```

So I'm stuck in getting these functions (`normalize`, `join`, etc.), can you help
with getting all possible exports from module by using `ts-morph` or naked typescript API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this using symbols, but it is possible to get the properties on the `path` object by checking its type:

```
const defaultImport = importDeclaration.getDefaultImportOrThrow();
const defaultImportType = defaultImport.getType();

for (const property of defaultImportType.getProperties()) {
  console.log(property.getName());
}
```

Outputs:

```
normalize
join
resolve
isAbsolute
relative
dirname
basename
extname
sep
delimiter
parse
format
toNamespacedPath
posix
win32
```

Answer (score 2):

With an interactive typescript session via ts-node:

```
$ npx ts-node
> import path from 'path'
{}
> Object.keys(path)
[
  'resolve',    'normalize',
  'isAbsolute', 'join',
  'relative',   'toNamespacedPath',
  'dirname',    'basename',
  'extname',    'format',
  'parse',      'sep',
  'delimiter',  'win32',
  'posix',      '_makeLong'
]
>
```